# How to extract an rgb image from a .ply file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera, point-cloud-library

I am trying to obtain an RGB image from a point cloud file. I have opened the file in Matlab using the following function:

```
ptCloud = pcread('final.ply')
```

it displays the following properties of the pointcloud: pointCloud with properties:

```
 Location: [256601×3 single]
    Count: 256601
  XLimits: [1×2 single]
  YLimits: [1×2 single]
  ZLimits: [1×2 single]
    Color: [256601×3 uint8]
   Normal: []
Intensity: []
```

Now to obtain the RBG image from, it I used the following lines of commands:

```
I = ptCloud.Color
imshow(I)
```

However this just outputs an blank figure window, with no image shown. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, then .ply files store 3D point cloud data. This means that you won't be able to display it using `imshow`. Instead, you need to use `pcread` in the computer vision toolbox to read in the point cloud, and `pcshow` to display the point cloud.

Details and an example can be found [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcread.html).